# Bootstrap image gallery, can't load own Flickr images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blueimp, flickr

I just downloaded [Bootstrap Image Gallery](http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/), but am having a hard time loading my images from Flickr. In the demo.js file, there is an AJAX call to load the images from Flickr.

I'm not familiar with JS or AJAX calls to be honest, but in looking at the code, it seems to be as **simple as replacing the API key**. (The base URL formula is lopped together from photo specifications that Flickr has already defined based on where they are storing the data in their servers.)

Yet it's not working for me. Two issues:

1. When I replace the API_key with mine, the original demo images are still being loaded! But to make sure that the API_key is actually being used, if I replace it with nothing or random key, the images do not load.
2. When I replace the method with `flickr.photosets.getPhotos` (and add requisite photoset_id right after API key), no images appear. In fact, despite the fact that I've tried multiple methods to call photos per [Flickr API docs](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/), only the original `flickr.interestingness.getList` works

Any thoughts on this? All I want to do is to call my photos using my API_Key, and then use the method flickr.photosets.getPhotos (returns photos from one specific set).

Relevant code below

```
// Load demo images from flickr:
$.ajax({
    url: (window.location.protocol === 'https:' ?
            'https://secure' : 'http://api') +
            '.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    data: {
        format: 'json',
        method: 'flickr.interestingness.getList',
        api_key: '7617adae70159d09ba78cfec73c13be3'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
}).done(function (result) {
    var linksContainer = $('#links'),
        baseUrl;

    // Add the demo images as links with thumbnails to the page:
    $.each(result.photos.photo, function (index, photo) {
        baseUrl = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' +
            photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret;
        $('<a/>')
            .append($('<img>').prop('src', baseUrl + '_s.jpg'))
            .prop('href', baseUrl + '_b.jpg')
            .prop('title', photo.title)
            .attr('data-gallery', '')
            .appendTo(linksContainer);
    });
});
```

Comment: Put `console.log(result)` at the very beginning of your `done` function, and check what that outputs to the browser console. That these API methods return errors when something went wrong, you could have found out by a short look into the API documentation (which I assume you did not bother with?). Please start reading docs, instead of just going by trial-and-error (without even checking for possible errors).

Comment: @CBroe Yes I did read all of the documentation, but as mentioned I'm not familiar with Ajax or JS, and unless I grossly glossed over it, the documentation doesn't mention the Ajax Flickr call at all. As well, I'm not saying the page doesn't load, it just doesn't load with the right images, the calls are working fine and no errors are being thrown. Indeed this is the case after I tried to put in console.log(result). Do you have any other thoughts that I could try?

Comment: Form the docs, it doesn’t seem to me that `flickr.interestingness.getList` is supposed to deliver photos specific to the viewing user/app, but just what Flickr considers “interesting photos” in general – that would of course mean you get the _same_ set of photos. And what does the console output show for `flickr.photosets.getPhotos`?

Comment: output appears to be the same, no errors are being thrown at the demo.js file that this code is in

Answer (score 1):

You could also use local images instead of Flickr.  Look for "The container for the list of example images" and paste the following in the source file.

```
    <!-- The container for the list of example images -->
    <div id="links"><div id="links">
    <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Sample Image 1" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Sample Image 2" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/apple.jpg" alt="Apple">
    </a>
    <a href="images/orange.jpg" title="Sample Image 3" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/orange.jpg" alt="Orange">
    </a>
</div>
```

Delete the following:

```
    // Load demo images from flickr:
$.ajax({
    data: {
        format: 'json',
        method: 'flickr.interestingness.getList',
        api_key: '7617adae70159d09ba78cfec73c13be3'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
}).done(function (result) {
    var linksContainer = $('#links'),
        baseUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

What ended up happening is that I could never figure this out, and after looking at Bootstrap Image Gallery, Responsive Image Gallery, Touch Touch, FancyBox, SimpleViewer, I went with [Galleria](http://www.galleria.io). Not to say that the others were bad, but that from the point of view of a beginner to front end, with 0 experience in JavaScript, nothing is easier to set up than Galleria.

They tell you exactly where everything goes, to the point of simplicity that they talk about  and  tags. And for more advanced users, you can skip right through this.

Not to mention, Galleria is incredibly well documented and it's very intuitive to manually add easy customizations to their theme (literally if I can do it, anyone can). And their native Flickr API is ridiculously easy... no API key, just the photoset_id (assuming it's public) and you're good to go!

I'm such a fan...

Yes I realize this is not an exact answer to my question, but a roundabout hack that others might find worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:  Comment out 'use strict', replace api_key and user_id with your values

```
$(function () {
// 'use strict';

// Load demo images from flickr:
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    data: {
        format: 'json',
        method: 'flickr.people.getPublicPhotos',
        api_key: 'ef8882888fcdd8885769c8881d888c6d',
        user_id: '98888889@N08'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
}).done(function (result) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it with an existing album in my own flickr account. 
Use the method: 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos' and loop through the result.photoset.photo. gives you something like this:

```
$(function () {
'use strict';
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    data: {
        format: 'json',
        method: 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
        photoset_id: '<ALBUM ID>',
        api_key: '<API KEY>'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
}).done(function (result) {
    var linksContainer = $('#links'),
        baseUrl;
    $.each(result.photoset.photo, function (index, photo) {
        baseUrl = 'https://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' +
            photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret;
        $('<a/>')
            .append($('<img>').prop('src', baseUrl + '_q.jpg'))
            .prop('href', baseUrl + '_b.jpg')
            .prop('title', photo.title)
            .attr('data-gallery', '')
            .appendTo(linksContainer);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cris' solution is correct. 
Just change:
$.each(result.photos.photo, function (index, photo)
to
$.each(result.photoset.photo, function (index, photo)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).